# Custom Security Token Service - Implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, claims-based-identity, sts-securitytokenservice

I'm working on an MVC 4 project. Actually the project involves 3 modules which talk to each other. User can buy licence to any of the 3 modules or all of it. I need to implement a single sign-on for the website that we are creating. So we decided to go with Security Token Service since it will be more secure.

I've read about STS and i have the basic knowledge of how it works. But the problem comes when i need to implement it in an actual project. Honestly i don't really know how to implement it. Can anyone tel me how to implement an Custom STS? (I'm working on .NET framework 4.5, MVC 4 & Visual Studio 2012).

According to my understanding all i need is to inherit `ClaimsAuthenticationManager` and override `Authenticate` method? (Correct me if i'm wrong). If thats the case where do i verify the username & password? Already i've done a little implementation

```
public override ClaimsPrincipal Authenticate(string resourceName, ClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal)
    {
        if (!incomingPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return base.Authenticate(resourceName, incomingPrincipal);
        }
        return DressUpPrincipal(incomingPrincipal.Identity.Name);
    }
```

in the above code `incomingPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is always `false`. How do i authenticate the user in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you look at [IdentityServer](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2).

> Thinktecture IdentityServer is a light-weight security token service built with .NET 4.5, MVC 4, Web API and WCF.

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer pepo. Actually i've already gone through thinktecture. The problem with that is that when i need to create a new user for my website, i need to go to thinktecture to do so. But i need to be able to create users on my own site. Is that possible?

Comment: yes, it is. IdentityServer has many extension points. You can set it up (by implementing some interface) to use you own database with users. You can find more about extending IdentityServer [here](http://brockallen.com/2013/02/03/integrating-thinktecture-identityserver-database-with-an-existing-database/). The good part is that you don't have to implement all the security logic (STS) and only do some plumbing between your user management and IdentityServer.